# Determine which range a character falls into

Tags: javascript

I am categorizing terms depending on what letter the term starts with.  What is the cleanest way to do so?

```
var parentGroup,
    startsWith = "H"; // Just simplifying and giving a static example here.

switch(startsWith) {
    case "A":
    case "B":
    case "C":
    case "D":
    case "E":
    case "F":
        parentGroup = "A-F";
        break;
    case "G":
    case "H":
    case "I":
    case "J":
    case "K":
    case "L":
    case "M":
        parentGroup = "G-M";
        break;
    case "N":
    case "O":
    case "P":
    case "Q":
    case "R":
        parentGroup = "N-R";
        break;
    case "S":
    case "T":
    case "U":
    case "V":
    case "W":
    case "X":
    case "Y":
    case "Z":
        parentGroup = "S-Z";
        break;
    default:
        parentGroup = "0-9";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those "parent groups" look a lot like [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), specifically character sets.  You could perform regular expression matches for patterns like `^[A-F]`.

```js
function parentGroup(char) {
    var groups = ['A-F', 'G-M', 'N-R', 'S-Z', '0-9'];
    for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        if (char.match('^[' + groups[i] + ']')) {
            return groups[i];
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById('in').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('out').textContent = parentGroup(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<div>Enter text, starting with a digit or uppercase letter: <input id="in" type="text" size="10"></div>
<div>Parent group: <span id="out"></span></div>
```

Comment: I initially thought a regular expression would be the way to do it, but didn't remember that you could do letter ranges like that.  Thanks! Exactly what I needed.